# The tag "paper"

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [paper](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper) deals with two subjects that have nothing to do with each other: physical paper (the stuff one writes on) and academical papers. I don't think a tag that deals with two unrelated subjects is helpful - I believe it should be split up.

There are two ways to split it:

1. Add [academic-paper](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-paper) and keep [paper](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper) only for sheets of paper.
2. Move the questions about academic papers to [academic-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing).

Which one is preferable?

(I thought at first that questions about the material one writes on could go under [handwriting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handwriting), but we have [What paper stock should I use for the soft cover of my book?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/30557/14704) for example. It wouldn't fit there. Of course, it could go under [publishing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) with no more specific tags...)

---

**Edit:**

Edited the tag info to refer only to physical paper, pointed the rest to [academic-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing). Started doing the retagging. Which is when I realised most of the questions under the tag are about either academic writing or essays. Less than ten questions are about physical paper. Of those, most would fit under [handwriting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handwriting), and the rest under [publishing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing). Which leads me to propose a new solution: maybe the logical thing to do is put the handwriting questions under [handwriting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handwriting), the questions about paper stock for books under [publishing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing), and keep [paper](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper) as a synonym for [academic-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing)? Or maybe get rid of it at all?

Comment: #2.  I see no reason to create a new tag that is a synonym of an existing one.  But do we need [paper]?  Looking at the questions it does seem there are several legit questions about actual paper.  Enough to justify a tag?  Or should [paper] be a synonym of [tools]?  Or merged?  This may be the example of something that fits under [tools] but not a sub-heading.

Comment: Comment post-edit:  I say do not keep [paper] unless it's about physical paper.  We already have [essay] and [article] and [academic-writing].  We probably need to clarify those (AW can be a frosh college student's history paper or a high level prof's journal article).  My preference is to either keep [paper] for paper or merge it with [tools] and edit that guidance to include paper.  This will help people find it on searches, yes?

Comment: @Cyn Didn't even know we had [tag:article]. It has 3 questions under it, no tag wiki, no usage guide. Could be merged into [tag:academic-writing], I think.

Comment: We have some odd overlaps and yeah, let's do some merging.  We have [scientific-publishing] and [essay] (which says "the definition is vague, overlapping with those of an article...) and [publication] (which is a synonym of [publishing] but ugh maybe it should just go away) and [academic-writing] and [technical-writing] and [business-writing].  All types of nonfiction.  And yes, [non-fiction] too.  I'm not in any way suggesting we shouldn't have different subsets of nonfiction, I just wonder if they can or should be rearranged.

Comment: @Cyn I looked again at [tag:article], one of the questions was about a magazine article, so [tag:journalism]. Making [article] a confusing and not useful tag. I can see why we'd need both [tag:essay] and [tag:academic-writing]: essays are more of a school assignment, they focus on different things than a scientific article. At least, as far as I understand. [tag:scientific-publishing] - I guess I can see the logic in keeping it separate from [tag:publishing] and from [tag:academic-writing]. We have both [tag:non-fiction] and [tag:creative-non-fiction], which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Cyn (cont) but I would keep [tag:non-fiction], if only as a catch-all for stuff we have no tag for. Remember my memorial plaque question? What other tag would you have put on that?

Comment: Magazine articles are not journalism!  Sure they can be.  But most are specialized topic nonfiction.  The tag [academic-writing] has been used for student papers a lot.  Some academics publish articles on science and some publish in other fields (history or pedagogy or literary analysis).  Ditto for books by academics.

Comment: I agree we should keep [non-fiction].

Comment: [creative-non-fiction] has one question.  I say merge it with [non-fiction] and be done with it.  What say you @MonicaCellio ?

Answer (score 4):

Good catch.  Tag "homonyms" like that are confusing.

Between those options, I definitely prefer moving those questions to [academic-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing).  The distinction between papers and other forms of academic writing is too fine-grained to matter with our current body of questions, and I don't anticipate that changing.

I don't know if we need [paper](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper) as distinct from [publishing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) (for that one question) and [handwriting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handwriting), but I don't see harm in keeping it for now.  We can always revisit it later, once the cluster of tags around tools settles down.  Let's retag the ones about *academic papers* appropriately and leave the rest alone.

Comment: Apparently (Cyn's catch) we also have [tag:article]. It has 3 questions under it. Two also have [tag:academic-writing] on them, so they mean an academic article. The third is about a school magazine article, so I've added [tag:journalism]. [tag:article] is therefore unclear. Can it just go?

Comment: @Galastel sounds like article should just go, yes.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Monica that there's likely too little difference between [academic-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing) and [academic-paper](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-paper) to really matter for us. It might be a useful distinction on, say, Academia, but probably not on Writing.

My vote is for just [academic-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing).

We might want to rework the tag wiki excerpt slightly too, to remove the academic paper example. Better to point people to [academic-writing], then.

As for [What paper stock should I use for the soft cover of my book?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/30557/2533), we do have [book-cover](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-cover) which seems like it would fit nicely.

Comment: True for your last line.  But not all the paper questions are about covers.  Some are about paper used in a book and others about paper used for handwriting.  As someone who designed a promotional bookmark for a comic series, I can tell you that questions about paper really do come up.

Comment: @Cyn *"But not all the paper questions are about covers."* True; but that note was about that *one* question specifically, as one that was in one sense about [tag:paper] but *not* about an [tag:academic-paper].